# Having trouble getting Java to compile: cannot find file

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm very new to programming so let me just explains where I'm at:

- I have downloaded the most recent JDK
- I have changed the path variable in the environmental variables tab, javac does run by itself in the command prompt
- I have downloaded notepad++

So I created a very simple program, pretty much just a simple "hello world" deal...

```
public class pleaseWork {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please work");
      }
}
```

And saved it into a folder I have on my C drive but not anywhere in the java folder. I have it saved as pleaseWork.java.

So I go to the command line and if I just type javac it runs correctly, but if I type in javac pleaseWork.java I get an error -

javac: file not found: pleaseWork.java

So basically I'm asking if I need to save my notepad++ .java files in a certain place for them to compile in the command prompt or is it something else?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

Comment: What don't you understand in the error message? `javac` cannot find `pleaseWork.java` in the **current** directory

Comment: You said please in both the class name and the main method. I'm not sure what else you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Error `javac: file not found: pleaseWork.java` indicate that your `javac` command not able to locate file you have given in your command that is `pleaseWork.java`.

To compile file place in any folder you need to go upto the path where your JAVA file place, from that path execute command `javac pleaseWork.java`.

You are executing your `javac` command from the directory path where this java file is not present.

**Another way is**
You need to specify the full file path in the argument.
e.g `javac "C:\temp\pleaseWork.java"`

For more info visit [How to Run JAVA file from command promt.](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/windows-cmd.html)

Answer (score 0):

when you go to command prompt... first of all go back to c drive and set the path there. and compile it... and while saving program in notepad... please provide file name in double quotes like "programWorld.java" or else it will be saved as text file not java file. resulting in file not found error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `javac` is in your path (so you can run it from anywhere).  Then in your command prompt cd to the directory where your `pleaseWork.java` file is saved and call `javac` from there.

As an aside, it's standard form to name your classes and files in java starting with a capital letter (`PleaseWork.java`)

Answer (score 0):

To set the temporary path of JDK, you need to follow following steps: Try this and let me know if its still not working, then c:>cd yourNewFolderName then set path

Open command prompt
copy the path of jdk/bin directory
write in command prompt: set path=copied_path
For Example:

set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin